# Hide all the rows which is inserted newly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table which contains 4 rows and (Expand or Collapse) button initially,see the below image
[image]

When i click the (Expand or Collapse) button initially,need to insert new row in the middle of rows, i did it using the below code

```
 JQuery('#btnId').click(function() {
        var that = this;
        $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {                   
            $(object).after("<tr id=\"dispId\"><td>Full name:'"+i+"'</td><td></td></tr>")
        });
    });
```

and which in result
[image]

Again if click the (Expand or Collapse) button, i need to hide the rows which is inserted in the middle.Is there a way to do this using Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: Ah you again. :-D Wait a sec, I'll provide you an answer. ^^

Comment: `<tr id="dispId">` will create duplicate Ids, which is invalid HTML. Change it to class.

Comment: ok that i will do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var inc = 0;
JQuery('#btnId').click(function() {
        var that = this;
        inc++;
        $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {                   
            $(object).after("<tr class=\"dispId\"><td>Full name:'"+i+"'</td><td></td></tr>")
            if(inc%2==0){//remove at every second click
               $('tr .dispId').eq(i).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple.

1. mark all items as new before adding them
2. if you want to hide them, just remove the last inserted rows (as they are marked)

Here is the code:

```
JQuery('#btnId').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    IF ($("newRow", "#example tbody").length = 0){ // add rows if no rows exists
        $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {                   
            $(object).after("<tr class="newRow" id=\"dispId\"><td>Full name:'"+i+"'</td><td></td></tr>")
        });
    } // remove rows if already exist
    else {
        $("newRow", "#example tbody").remove()
    }
});
```

Comment: i have only one button '#btnId' on click of that i need to do this..some one down (-1) to ur ans..

Comment: Well then its simple. Just use toggle.

Comment: I've changed the example, due to the fact that the current solution only works if every second row should be removed. If you add more than one row, the code would fail.